# How can I preserve creation dates when packing/unpacking 7z files?

Tags: windows, 7-zip, archiving, date, date-modified

From my tests, when unpacking files from a `.7z` archive, 7-zip preserves the "last modified" date but sets the creation date to the time of the file extraction (unpacking).

Is there any way to preserve all 3 dates (created, last modified, last accessed) or at least the former two ?